# How would an alien race destroy all nuclear weapons on earth?

Tags: aliens, earth-like, nuclear, nuclear-weapons

An alien race has decided that earth is the best place to recruit new soldiers and prepare for a war, and they want to eliminate all nuclear weapons (explosive ones, not dirty bombs) to prevent earthlings from being able to retaliate against them conquering everyone on earth and making them their slaves.

Where are the obvious first places to look? Nuclear missile silos, obviously, and nuclear submarines. What other publicly known locations should they be looking for to find nuclear weapons so they can disable all of them? They might miss a few of course, but they want to get 99% of the bombs so earth is mostly free from nuclear war.

Is there a particular process they should follow to get all the nuclear weapons, like abducting the president or prime minister of every country?

Ideal answers will involve less work by the aliens. For example, abducting every human and using alien probes to try and work out where every nuke is is an option, but it would be very hard and complicated, vs just lasering a few thousand sites from orbit.

Comment: Make them angry enough to throw them at you. Catch them when they throw them? Isn't this  about unknowns in the real world - and doesn't the answer come down to story-writing more than worldbuilding? Since we don't know where the others are, isn't it just a bit of story-writing to say where they would best fit the narrative as to how to get them?

Comment: They want to avoid a nuclear war, so starting one seems risky. Is it unknown? Maybe there's a set of people you could abduct to find out, or a set of major targets you could vaporize. I assume some people who are more into the military know.

Comment: Asking about plans isn't about worldbuilding, that's more of a story development, and writing process than establishing some fact about your world. Questions asking about what a character or organization will do is explicitly off topic for this site.

Comment: NICE TRY, GREYS.

Comment: Get a Kryptonian to do it?

Comment: On a more serious note, what kind of technology are we looking at?  Star Trek teleporters would result in a greatly different answer than Babylon 5 or Star Wars levels of tech.  And what about the aliens themselves? Can they intermingle with Humans?  Can they survive on Earth?

Comment: This question is about the tools they need to accomplish a goal, not about their plan. The answers have been on point for this, giving satellite scanning, multi spectral scans, collimated neutron beams, and von neumann machines, along with a a frame shift challenge that it's not worth it.

Comment: In story they have a tech tree since they warp in on one ship with very limited resources, so they can build anything up to and beyond star trek teleporters or babylon 5 ships, but the higher the tech level the more time it takes to build up, and the more ships they need the more time they need to build it up. None of which is necessary, as someone noted a satellite and a neutron gun could do it pretty easily. 

They want soldiers for a war, so quicker is better.

Comment: Detonation, perhaps?

Comment: There was a story about some anti-nuke group of humans which found a way to make all Uranium and Plutonium non-reactive. So no more bombs. But no more nuclear power plants, either. Unintended consequences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from missile silos and submarines (and aircraft carriers), there are also SAC bases where aircraft-delivered nuclear bombs are bunkered, as well as both Navy and Air Force bases where missile warheads and nuclear armed cruise missiles may be present, military bases in Europe where tactical nuclear missiles are stored -- there are a lot of warheads out there and they're scattered very widely to prevent them being too easy to destroy with a pre-emptive strike.

Of course, the equivalent locations in Russia, China, UK, France, India, etc.

However, "publicly known" locations aren't really needed.  Any interlopers with the technology to remotely disable or destroy nuclear weapons ought to also have technology to remotely detect and identify a bomb's "pit" -- the small amount of nearly pure plutonium in a fairly compact mass that triggers whatever other reactions may take place in a modern nuke (three-stage or fusion-boosted, for instance).

They might possibly miss a very small number of "old technology" uranium bombs, but most likely they'd be able to identify those as well; similar to modern designs, they'd have a relatively small amount of high purity metallic uranium enriched well above natural occurrence of U-235.

It is widely rumored that (some) US surveillance satellites are capable of detecting and identifying a bomb pit inside, for instance, a shipping container or truck body from orbit and pinpointing its location within a few meters (should get you the right container, for instance).  They can't, as far as I've heard, tell where the bomb was built (as would be the case with, for instance, emission analysis from close up or of fallout after detonation) -- but a civilization that can travel between stars and still have an agenda when they reach their destination might well be able to locate the pits more precisely and do a better job of narrowing down the isotope mix -- to be able, for instance, to tell how old the pit is and where it was made, if they care.

Comment: I presume the pits produce gamma radiation a drone flying nearby could detect, so they could laser it.

Comment: US surveillance satellites are said to be able to detect and track bomb pits in, for instance, trucks or shipping containers.  Star travelers are likely to be better at this.

Comment: That does make it very easy for them.

Comment: While all the answers were valuable, this answer was chosen because it gave clear military worldbuilding that gives settings, locations, and tools needed to accomplish the goal chosen.

Answer (score 8):

**"Mr Kim, give me a multi-spectral scan."**

[image]

This is Ensign Harry Kim. Ensign Harry Kim loves to scan. And he has not done a good scan all day. His hand is up and he is ready for the job.

Simply tell the good ensign to use ship's sensors to scan the planet for anything that might be a nuclear weapon.

Nuclear weapons have a lump of decaying plutonium (or uranium) in them. The decay makes them shoot out particles all over the place.  It is easy to detect their emissions using the ship's sensors.

"Right away, Captain." Ensign Harry Kim bends his head and goes typedy typedy type on his console and we hear beepedy beepedy boop.

"Eight thousand four hundred and ninety three signatures detected, Captain."

"Fine work, Mr Kim. Have the data sent to my ready room."

Then it is simply a matter of plotting the most efficient course around the planet as we launch a bomb at each missile site. This is actually much harder than the scanning and harder even than the space travel to get here.

There are about $10^{27750}$ possible courses to choose from. That's $100...0$ with $27750$ zeroes! The ship's computer would take a kajillion years to test them all. We don't have that long.

Fortunately I know a certain ensign who has some computational heuristics he's been eager to try out. . . .

Comment: Did you just bring up TSP!?

Comment: “Then it is simply a matter of plotting the most efficient course around the planet as we launch a bomb at each missile site.” It may be far more efficient to launch a large number of smaller ships to drop those bombs, or just use drone bombs, instead of moving one ship around the planet to pick each target site off in passing. It might be harder to detect from the ground too, so there is an extra element of surprise, and it is likely harder to target each smaller vehicle and organise a defence, especially if they can hang high initially and drop to their targets at a single coordinated time.

Answer (score 6):

With collimated neutron beams.

This has the interesting effect of detonating them (possibly at lower/fizzle yields).

How to collimate neutron beams I leave as an exercise for the reader. It's something a first year student should be able to manage with the weak force manipulation instruments in the lab.

Comment: Love it! One question though. Can you expand upon any other effects one might expect of planetary bombardment with CNBs? Would you sterilize any life in the affected area, or give them cancer? Would you convert any of the affected mass into radioactive isotopes? I could be way off base, but it feels like a useful bit of info if you're able to provide it.

Comment: Interesting. This has been proposed on Earth, and may be a reality in half a century or so. https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn3734-neutrino-beam-could-neutralise-nuclear-bombs/

Comment: @Qami, the effects depend on how good your aim is.  Anything in the target area is likely to become radioactive from [neutron activation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_activation), so the tighter the beam, the less collateral damage there is.

Comment: Also see "Neutron Beam Analysis Helps Inspectors Check Dismantled Nuclear Bombs" https://www.technologynetworks.com/analysis/news/neutron-beam-analysis-helps-inspectors-check-dismantled-nuclear-bombs-324623

Comment: That's pretty cool as an idea to slaughter nukes. It also avoids excessive collateral damage.

Comment: @NepeneNep Other than setting them off, you mean?

Comment: @Qami You'd make all kinds of weird radioactive isotopes out of all matter around the target, and pretty much instantly kill anyone near it. But that's only for the split second it takes for the nuke to cook off (unless it's a fizzle yield, I suppose...). This is much more than a "give them cancer" thing if hit by the beam, their lights just turn off. If the nuke doesn't go off and they wander into the area after it's stopped firing despite their geiger counters going nuts, they're in for a bad next few days of the rest of their lives.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond That looks even more interesting (and more plausible) than my answer. They're using neutrinos... which have the interesting property of being able to fire *through* planets to hit their target. Neutrons could only be able to hit things on the surface or just under it from orbit. Not sure how it works... inverse beta decay or some crap like that? I really have trouble believing we're less than a century away from that sort of thing... my answer is (or was, I though) purely in the realm of science fiction.

Comment: They don't care about killing a few nuclear scientists and such, no. And nukes don't go off when you blast them, they require extremely sensitively timed explosions.

Comment: @NepeneNep They do require rather delicate implosions... but only to concentrate enough neutrons that you can cleave a significant fraction of nuclei all within a few nanoseconds of each other. If you supply those neutrons externally...

Answer (score 3):

**Don't Bother**

There are essentially three threats:

1. The primates' slow, pitiful rockets used against your vessels in space. That's a laugh: Those can barely reach the altitude of low orbit without lots of warning, most cannot track or hit moving targets, and most are easily detected, dodged, and/or lasered.

   While in high orbit, put out a few decoys to attract the best rockets, then use those bogies for target practice.
2. Attack upon a ground location.

   Piffle: Don't build a ground base. Don't land ground forces. Make the new slaves build spaceplanes and come to your well-protected orbital Slave Center. When a slave delivery is late, drop a rock on them. Doesn't matter where. There's *billions* of them, and they keep breeding. If they were smart enough to defy you, they would have built better rockets (see #1).
3. Smuggled fissiles onto your Slave Center and/or ships.

   Won't Work #1: Your surveillance network can detect the regular sources of radiation, and knows how many gamma rays each should statistically be detected during each orbital pass. When the foolish primates move some mass, the amount of radiation changes, and the primates get a rock dropped on them. Doesn't matter where.

   Won't Work #2: Ascending spaceplanes get checked. More than expected radiation? Laser target practice. And drop a rock. Teach those stupid primates a lesson.

If a couple primate chieftans want to nuke *each other*, so what? There are billions of slaves down there. The planet is a slave mine, and mines often have a slag heap.

Comment: I'd say that's the entire point in getting rid of these weapons. When you start a slave farm, you don't want your slaves with capability to murder each other en masse. They wouldn't be worried about retaliation, they'd be worried about profits from the farm.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen curbing the self-genocidal impulses of the slaves should depend upon the export market. For example: If your vast fleet of transports will export, say, ten million news slave-conscripts each year, that's still merely one tenth of one percent of the current primate population. Even if they murdered 90% of their population, there's still a century of exports...and they can breed exponentially during that century right back up to billions. Besides, if one of the uppity primates looks like they are going to get all genocidal, you can just drop a couple rocks on their tribe.

Comment: Lots of nuclear wars might make your slave race sick, so they want to avoid that. They want healthy virile slaves.

Answer (score 0):

**Von Neumann Machines**

This works best if you're not in a hurry.

Breed up a few billion or so and sprinkle them everywhere, with instructions to breed and explore.

Any one that comes across plutonium or uranium snips a tiny bit of it and then crawls in a random direction for as long as it can.

(Teaching them to leave reactors alone is left as an exercise for the interested student.)

Comment: One of their goals is to do less work, so scanning every inch of the planet with machines is a bit more work.

Comment: Who's scanning the planet? The VNMs simply crawl around, get into everything, and tear up any lumps of fissionable isotopes that they find.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer that was mentioned about scanning for signs of radioactive decay to detect nuclear devices, another thing that can be done is orbital bombardment. Attacking the regions near their nuclear supplies by launching debris and items from orbit at the planet would be a good way to pacify the population. It could be a strike from orbit that would be like a nuclear war without the radiation, but with very devastating effects. A quick enough attack could devastate the planet without Earth having a chance to respond and after the devastation, you may still have enough people alive to recruit who would be desperate for a nice undestroyed place to live and a decent meal... meaning they will easily play right into the aliens hands.